# Append filename as additional column but with modification using awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to add the filename as a new column to file contents, but also removing sections of the name, all using awk.

Currently using the following code which gets me almost there:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,FILENAME}' A0631-Somatic-WGS.format.flt.txt

File contents:
X   120143898   6   88725363    A0631-Somatic-WGS.format.flt.txt
X   147991648   6   132706871   A0631-Somatic-WGS.format.flt.txt
```

I want the filename to only maintain the name, not anything following the first period. So ideal output would look like:

```
File contents:
X   120143898   6   88725363    A0631-Somatic-WGS
```

I'm thinking of doing ${FILENAME%.format.flt.txt}, but I can't get awk to accept this as part of its command. I'm fairly sure this is possible though!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use `sub` on `FILENAME` to remove anything starting with a DOT:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' '{fn=FILENAME; sub(/\..+/, "", fn);
print $1,$2,$3,$4,fn}' A0631-Somatic-WGS.format.flt.txt

X   120143898   6   88725363    A0631-Somatic-WGS
X   147991648   6   132706871   A0631-Somatic-WGS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; split(ARGV[1],f,".")}
      {print $1,$2,$3,$4,f[1]}' A0631-Somatic-WGS.format.flt.txt
X       120143898       6       88725363        A0631-Somatic-WGS
X       147991648       6       132706871       A0631-Somatic-WGS
```

Answer (score 1):

or just let `OFS` take care of all of it :

> ```
> mawk ++NF OFS= FS='[.][^ \t]+[ \t]*$'
> ```

```
X   120143898   6   88725363    A0631-Somatic-WGS
X   147991648   6   132706871   A0631-Somatic-WGS
```

A great use-case for "greedy" `regex` matching

I suppose you can also do it  the `RS` way :

> ```
> gawk FS RS='[.][^ \t]+[ \t]*\r?\n'
> ```

```
X   120143898   6   88725363    A0631-Somatic-WGS
X   147991648   6   132706871   A0631-Somatic-WGS
```